# Trying to move data from NVARCHAR to TEXT in HANA

Tags: hana

A column in a SAP HANA database have been NVARCHAR and we have expanded it to max but have no realized that we need to replace it with a TEXT (NCLOB) field.

I know that this isn't possible with a simple alter table, so i'm using the Add column, copy data, drop column, rename column pattern to do this.

In the second step though i run into problem. I get the infamous: `SAP DBTech JDBC: [7]: feature not supported: cannot support non-constant types`

Searching gave me this [answer](https://answers.sap.com/questions/11518315/use-a-function-to-update-a-column.html).

So i tried to do it like this:

```
UPDATE "DLN1" as "T1" SET "U_ITCO_OGPID_A" = ( SELECT TO_NCLOB("U_ITCO_OGPID") as "U_ITCO_OGPID_A" FROM "DLN1" as "T2" WHERE "T1"."DocEntry" = "T2"."DocEntry" AND "T1"."LineNum" = "T2"."LineNum" );
```

But it errors out with the same error message.

Is there something else that i can try?

The column descriptions:

```
 ;SCHEMA_NAME   ;TABLE_NAME;TABLE_OID;COLUMN_NAME   ;POSITION;DATA_TYPE_ID;DATA_TYPE_NAME;OFFSET;LENGTH       ;SCALE;IS_NULLABLE;DEFAULT_VALUE;COLLATION;COMMENTS;MAX_VALUE;MIN_VALUE;CS_DATA_TYPE_ID;CS_DATA_TYPE_NAME;DDIC_DATA_TYPE_ID;DDIC_DATA_TYPE_NAME;COMPRESSION_TYPE;INDEX_TYPE;COLUMN_ID;PRELOAD;GENERATED_ALWAYS_AS;HAS_SCHEMA_FLEXIBILITY;FUZZY_SEARCH_INDEX;FUZZY_SEARCH_MODE;MEMORY_THRESHOLD;LOAD_UNIT;GENERATION_TYPE;IS_CACHABLE;IS_CACHE_KEY;ROW_ORDER_POSITION
1;ZZ_SEPTOB_TEST;DLN1      ;3 164 003;U_ITCO_OGPID  ;297     ;-9          ;NVARCHAR      ;2 120 ;100          ;?    ;TRUE       ;?            ;         ;?       ;?        ;?        ;83             ;STRING           ;32               ;INVALID            ;DEFAULT         ;NONE      ;3 164 300;FALSE  ;?                  ;FALSE                 ;FALSE             ;?                ;?               ;COLUMN   ;?              ;FALSE      ;FALSE       ;?                 
2;ZZ_SEPTOB_TEST;DLN1      ;3 164 003;U_ITCO_OGPID_A;306     ;-10         ;TEXT          ;1 624 ;2 147 483 647;?    ;TRUE       ;?            ;         ;?       ;?        ;?        ;86             ;TEXT             ;32               ;INVALID            ;DEFAULT         ;NONE      ;3 668 609;TRUE   ;?                  ;FALSE                 ;FALSE             ;?                ;?               ;COLUMN   ;?              ;FALSE      ;FALSE       ;?
```

Best Regards,

Leif

Comment: What's the reason for the self-join here? Why couldn't you use `UPDATE "DLN1" SET "U_ITCO_OGPID_A" = TO_NCLOB("U_ITCO_OGPID")` here? Also, check the indexserver trace file for more details on the error.

Comment: Oh, i had missed to add the link! Because of this little piece of hint i found: https://answers.sap.com/questions/11518315/use-a-function-to-update-a-column.html

Going for the logs...

Comment: Checked the indexserver logfiles, nothing related shows up unfortunately!

Comment: Can you explain why the simply `UPDATE` is not a viable option in this case? By the way, I just tried the `ALTER TABLE` approach and had no issues at all. I tried this on a HANA 1.22.08 database.

Comment: Because i get the "SAP DBTech JDBC: [7]: feature not supported: cannot support non-constant types" error when i try a simple update, googling on that lead me to try the alternative in my question.. Without any improvment.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is possible to do both ways with simple UPDATE and with ALTER so please check syntax in your code

I have created simple example for you

```sql
CREATE COLUMN TABLE aa (a_char NVARCHAR(10), a_clob NCLOB);
INSERT INTO aa (a_char) VALUES ('1');

--  simple update
UPDATE aa SET a_clob = TO_NCLOB(a_char);

-- alter from NVARCHAR to NCLOB
ALTER TABLE aa ALTER (a_char NCLOB);
```

Comment: The post is asking for TEXT datatype.This is not working for TEXT datatype, please check the title question.Message Strip Success
`Could not execute 'ALTER TABLE aa ALTER (a_char TEXT)'
Error: (dberror) [7]: feature not supported: cannot change column data type to TEXT/SHORTTEXT/BINTEXT for column A_CHAR: line 15 col 22 (at pos 22)`